# How to create a project sheet via the python SDK

Tags: python-2.7, smartsheet-api

I'm trying to create new project sheets in a folder, however I can't find a way to ensure the sheet is a project sheet.

Here is my code so far:

```
def create_resource_sheet(name):
    """ Create a new resource sheet.

    :param name:
    :return:
    """
    folder_id = get_resource_folder_id()

    # TODO: Find and delete existing sheet with this name

    resource_sheet = SS.models.Sheet({
        'name': name,
        # 'gantt_enabled': True,  # This was added as an attempt to force it to a project sheet, but error 1032
        'columns': [{
            'title': 'Task',
            'type': 'TEXT_NUMBER',
            'primary': True,
            'width': 200
        }, {
            'title': 'Status',
            'type': 'PICKLIST',
            'options': ['wtg', 'hld', 'ip', 'rdy', 'rev', 'fin', 'omt'],  # TODO: Update this list
            'width': 180
        }, {
            'title': '% Complete',
            'type': 'TEXT_NUMBER',
            'tag': ['GANTT_PERCENT_COMPLETE'],
            'width': 85
        }, {
            'title': 'Assigned To',
            'type': 'CONTACT_LIST',
            'tag': ['GANTT_ASSIGNED_RESOURCE', 'GANTT_DISPLAY_LABEL'],
            'width': 150
        }, {
            'title': '% Use',
            'type': 'TEXT_NUMBER',
            'tag': ['GANTT_ALLOCATION'],
            'width': 60
        }, {
            'title': 'Days',
            'type': 'DURATION',
            'tag': ['GANTT_DURATION'],
            'width': 70
        }, {
            'title': 'Start',
            'type': 'ABSTRACT_DATETIME',
            'tag': ['CALENDAR_START_DATE', 'GANTT_START_DATE'],
            'width': 80
        }, {
            'title': 'Start',
            'type': 'ABSTRACT_DATETIME',
            'tag': ['CALENDAR_START_DATE', 'GANTT_START_DATE'],
            'width': 80
        }, {
            'title': 'Finish',
            'type': 'ABSTRACT_DATETIME',
            'tag': ['CALENDAR_END_DATE', 'GANTT_END_DATE'],
            'width': 80
        }, {
            'title': 'Type',
            'type': 'TEXT_NUMBER',
            'width': 150
        }, {
            'title': 'Comments',
            'type': 'TEXT_NUMBER',
            'width': 700
        }
        ]
    })

    response = SS.Folders.create_sheet_in_folder(folder_id, resource_sheet)
    new_sheet = response.result
    return new_sheet
```

I am getting the following error code:

> smartsheet.exceptions.ApiError: {"result": {"shouldRetry": false,
>   "code": 1142, "name": "ApiError", "errorCode": 1142, "recommendation":
>   "Do not retry without fixing the problem. ", "message": "Column type
>   DURATION is reserved for project sheets and may not be manually set on
>   a column.", "refId": "6gurrzzwhepe", "statusCode": 400}}

Is there a way I can create project sheets from scratch?

I have tried setting gantt_enabled to true but that just triggered a different error, so did setting 'project_settings'.

I have tried creating the sheet with just the primary column, then update_sheet to set project settings, which tells me: `To set projectSettings, you must first enable dependencies on the sheet.`

I have tried setting dependencies enabled, both directly in the create_sheet and in update_sheet, but both return: `The attribute(s) sheet.dependenciesEnabled are not allowed for this operation.`

I'm going to keep trying things, but I'm getting out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the sheet from a template, either using the global project template or a user defined template if you want to customize.

```
templates = SS.Templates.list_public_templates()
for template in templates.data:
    if template.global_template == 
smartsheet.models.enums.GlobalTemplate.PROJECT_SHEET:
    break
sheet = smartsheet.models.Sheet({
    'name': name,
    'from_id': template.id
})
resource_sheet = SS.Folders.create_sheet_in_folder(folder_id, sheet)
```

If you want to customize create a project sheet using the Smartsheet web UI, make your changes and then Save As Template. Once you have the template, grab the ID from the Properties if you don't want to search for it, or `SS.Templates.list_user_created_templates()`.

Comment: Thanks @timwells. I ended up using a similar technique. I made a template sheet which contains the minimum columns I need. As some sheets may need extra columns compared to others, I ended up creating the sheet based on the template, then modify the columns (mostly add new ones) programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a *new* dependency-enabled sheet through the API. You'll need to manually create a template and then use the API to make a copy.